# logical operation & pre-increment in c

Tags: c, logical-operators, pre-increment

Can any one explain why c still equal 15 after execution

```
int main(void)
{
    int t,a=5,b=10,c=15;
        t= ++a||++c;
        printf("%d  %d  %d",t,a,c);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The logical-or operator `||` is a short-circuit operator.  If the left side evaluates to a true boolean value (i.e. not 0), then the right side doesn't execute.

Similarly for the logical-and operator `&&`, if the left hand side is false (i.e. 0) the right hand side does not execute.